# Chromium Base Browser Control To Load Extension Each Time It Is Activated?

Tags: extension-methods, cefsharp

I am new to chromium based browser control.
Understand that tool like CefSharp and Awesomium are actually browser engine embedded in the application and will be disposed off when the application is close.
Is this means each time when the application is launch, the extension will need to be reloaded?
If the extension have configuration steps to be run before use, is this means that user will have to repeat these configuration steps each time when the application is re-activated?
Thank you.

Regards,
Jason Mah

Comment: What extension are you referring to exactly? I don't understand the question.

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for your prompt reply. I am trying to add Aspera Connect extension to the CefSharp browser. Aspera Connect extension is a tool to allow access to their cloud storage. We need to configure the download path after the extension installation. Is this mean each time the CefSharp browser is launched, user will need to repeat the configuration again?

Comment: By default an in memory cache is used,  to persist cookies/localstorage etc you need to specify a CachePath see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#need-to-knowlimitations I don't know anything about the extension you are referring to, have you confirmed it's working? CEF has limited extension support,  as CefSharp is just one of many chromium embedded framework wrappers, it's limited by the functionality CEF offers.

Comment: Thanks again @amaitland!
It seem like CefSharp does not support my extension program. Do you know of any browser wrapper that have better support for extension?
I know that Webview2 control from Microsoft also does not support extension.
I have also tried a different solution by using Webkit Browser wrapper too. But Webkit Browser control do not seem to support authentication request handler...

Comment: I'm not aware of any browser wrapper that fully supports extensions. CEF will at some point fully support extensions https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2969/support-chrome-windows-with-cef-callbacks If aspera offers an API you can probably write your own implementation (You can look at the extension JavaScript to see how exactly integrates with the browser)